# Battery discharge current

Tags: batteries, current-source, battery-chemistry

[image]

What is the meaning of standard discharge current mentioned on the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/346/CR2477N_v06-1943.pdf) of lithium batteries. Does it represent the maximum current load can take or it represent the instantaneous current battery can provide

Comment: Try linking to a data sheet.

Comment: Added the datasheet screenshoot. Battery is CR2477N

Comment: How about a link to the data sheet?

Comment: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/346/CR2477N_v06-1943.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Andyaka  for answering. I got answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the graphs for performance you will see that best cell capacity for various loads implies a minimum load resistance of about 3 kohm. Much lower than this and cell capacity drops from about ~900 mAh potentially down to ~600mAh at 1k loading. These approximately correspond to currents of 1mA (3k load) and 2.5mA (1.2 k load) and approximately tie in with the "standard" and "max" discharge currents: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The battery capacity is stated at 950mAh .This occurs at a discharge current of 1mA. You can draw less and the battery capacity may not be 950mAh .You are safe to draw up to 2.5mA but the battery capacity will probably be less than 950mAh . Do not draw more than 2.5 mA .